# Hspec deal with two IO actions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, hspec

My question is whether there are ways to test two `IO actions` in HSpec of Haskell?

Just something like the below example: (The below is wrong because of type)

```
  it "parse examples 0" $ liftM2 shouldBe (tests "ex0in.txt") (tests "ex0Out.txt")

  tests :: FileType -> IO (Either String String)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know `FileType`, I deal it equals `FilePath`.

## use do and liftIO

```
it "parse examples 0" $ do
  ex0in <- liftIO (tests "ex0in.txt")
  ex0out <- liftIO (tests "ex0Out.txt")
  ex0in `shouldBe` ex0out
```

## use join and liftIO

```
it "parse examples 0" $ join $ liftM2 shouldBe (liftIO (tests "ex0in.txt")) (liftIO (tests "ex0Out.txt"))
```